# In a quadrilateral ABCD, angle CAB equals angle DAC and angle BCA equals angle ACD. The area of ABCD IS 72 Sq cm. Find area of the triangle ACD?

Tags: geometry

I am sure that triangle ABC and ADC are similar and I think that AC divides the quad ABCD into two equals parts so should the answer be 36 sq cm?
Also is ABCD a parallelogram? And does the diagonal of a parallelogram divide it into two equal triangles?

[image]

Comment: can you post a Picture please?

Comment: It does not have to be a parallelogram, but if it *were* a  parallelogram then the diagonal *would* divide it into two equal triangles.

Comment: Hint: The two triangles are similar but in addition they share a common side.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner i am trying to upload the image but unfortunately i dont have 10+ reputation so it isnt allowing me to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question must assume a line AC that bisects the angles A and C. Using the knowledge that the line bisects these angles (note we do not know that angle A and C are equal, however, so a parallelogram is not necessary), we know that the area on both sides of the bisection must be equal. I.e. Think of each triangle separately - we know each has two congruent angles to the other triangle, so the third must be congruent also. Also, by our trigonometry laws, we know the triangles' areas must be equal since they share one side and have equal corresponding angles. Thus your line of thought was correct, the area of ACD is 36 sq. cm. and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the help